# How to simulate physical volume key pressed for all apps

Tags: java, android, simulation, keyevent, foreground

I want to simulate the actual volume keypress in android.
I have an app that runs in background and observers touch event. And on touch event, it should turn up the volume for the rest of the apps(ie all apps should believe that volume up key is pressed). 
Is there a way to do that?